# Why isn't this simple callback function working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm trying to use a callback function for the first time and am having trouble getting it working. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
var unsavedChanges = 1;

function saveData(callback)
{
    // save data

    if(typeof callback === "function")
    {
        unsavedChanges = 0;
        callback.apply(arguments);
    }
}

function nextStep(val)
{
    if(unsavedChanges == 1)
    {
        saveData(nextStep, val);
        return false;
    }

    console.log(val);
}

nextStep("test");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tXqn3/

Inside my real "saveData" function I'm saving data using `$.ajax()` and I have the callback in the `.done()` function. So, this way, if there's unsaved data on the page then it gets saved and then the original function that was called gets executed.

With this code, the value `undefined` gets printed out to the console when the code runs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `callback.apply(arguments)`? You're applying the callback to the callback??

Comment: @elclanrs I read that doing that calls the callback function with the arguments. I.e. it's the same as doing `callback(arguments[1], ...);`, but with the advantage that the arguments don't have to be hardcoded.

Comment: Can you post the "real" code. It's hard to determine what `arguments` is, if it's the set that includes `callback` or if it's the `done`'s arguments (since you mentioned it's wrapped in `done`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has two problems.

First, look at the definition of `apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

You're missing the first argument `thisArg`, which is what should be used as `this` within the function you're applying.

Second, I don't think you actually want to pass `arguments` into apply. What you want is all but the first argument, since the first argument is `callback`. So you can use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1)` to get all the arguments except the first, and pass this into `apply`.

Here's a working fiddle with these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/UkdT7/1/

Comment: Beat me to it, and solid explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a callback that accepts arguments, the simplest, idiomatic way to do this is to pass a closure which takes care of the argument passing:

```
var unsavedChanges = 1;

function saveData(callback)
{
    // save data

    if(typeof callback === "function")
    {
        unsavedChanges = 0;
        callback(); // no callback.apply
    }
}

function nextStep(val)
{
    if(unsavedChanges == 1)
    {
        saveData(function () { 
            nextStep(val);
        });
        return false;
    }

    console.log(val);
}

nextStep("test");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/YxDkg

Answer (score 1):

apply function gets the thisArg as first arugment and then array as second arguments so you need to do this

```
callback.apply(this,arguments);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: This isn't the full fix, however, as it won't log `"test"`.